# ClassCastException: com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneProxy

Tags: android

I'm newbie in Android.

I'm programing Instrumentation Tests for SIM ToolKit (STK)

I need to use CommandsInterface which is available only in PhoneBase Interface.
Once I have a Phone i'd like to use the following line:

```
private Phone   mPhone;
private Context    mContext;
private Handler    mHandler;
private CommandsInterface            mCmdIf;
private PhoneBase    mPhoneBase;

mPhoneBase = ((PhoneBase)mPhone);  <==== uncaught exception 
mCmdIf = mPhoneBase.mCM;
```

It compiled successfully, however gives uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
Please advice how to overcome this issue.
Thanks In Advance
Micha

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `PhoneBase` directly because it's an internal in android and not visible in the `SDK`. You can check your exception msg using logcat.

From the source code:

```
/**
 * (<em>Not for SDK use</em>) 
 * A base implementation for the com.android.internal.telephony.Phone interface.
 * 
 * Note that implementations of Phone.java are expected to be used
 * from a single application thread. This should be the same thread that
 * originally called PhoneFactory to obtain the interface.
 *
 *  {@hide}
 *
 */
```

I don't know what mCM is, but I guess you can get that information from [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html). You can get it doing

```
Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Thanks Macarse for your replay.

I didn't find any way to use TelephonyManager context in order to get the required CommandsInterface.
Does it mean it is private for PhoneApp only?

Comment: What I tried to explain is that the CommandsInterface is not available in the SDK. I guess you want that to get info from the phone, then you should get it from the TelephonyManager.